# Dropdown selectionchanged not firing in client server and firing in my dev server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I developed a web application with an aspx page containing 3 dropdowns, these dropdownlist have their propriety autopostback set to true with some events firing when their selectedtext changed

in my dev server, they are working properly without a problem but when deploying the web application in the client server, those events does not fire at all and the page does not load.

Does any of you have an idea why those events are not firing in client server and do in my dev server ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the correct version of .Net installed and selected for your web site's app pool?

Comment: yes the client machine has the framework 4.0 installed

Comment: After enabling active scripting in IE option the dropdown work.. is there a way to fire those events even if this option is diabled ? this web application will be used from different browsers and i don't want to oblige user to active scripting from their browser options